# Sublime Text 2 Make not working, can't find latex

Tags: build, latex, makefile

I'm a bit new to make, so this is probably something really very simple, but with the text editor I use (Sublime Text 2) it will automatically run make when I tell it to build my project.  When I do I get this output:

```
gcc ../src/TADA.c -o ../bin/TADA
cd ../aux
latex ../doc/documentation.tex
make: latex: No such file or directory
make: *** [report] Error 1
```

However, if I cd to the project's directory and run make it works just fine.  For some reason when I run it from Sublime Text 2 it can't seem to find the latex command.  Anyone have any guesses as to why that occurs?

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `latex`.  (I can't give you any more specifics because you didn't mention what sort of OS you are trying this on.)

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.  Wouldn't latex be installed if I can run it from the terminal?

Comment: Yes, it would.  In that case it's probably a `PATH` issue.  If your `latex` command works while your `make` command doesn't, without any intermediate commands issues in between, look at any redefinitions of the variables `PATH` and/or `SHELL` in your `Makefile`(s).

Answer (score 0):

Yo should install:

http://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html

and then added to the path:

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/.. ## complete path